# Limit on big ints sign too far away

Tags: packages

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amstext,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bigints}

\begin{document}

$$
\bigintss^x_0 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^2}dz
$$
\end{document}
```

My problem is that the lower limit is too far to the right. Any suggestions as to how to move it closer to the integral sign?

Comment: Please have a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 1):

The coding in that package is a little, strange, and it is likely to produce some spacing weirdness, but it also only supports `_` being used before `^`

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amstext,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bigints}

\begin{document}

a
\[
\int^x_0 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^2}dz
\]

b
\[
\bigintss^x_0 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^2}dz
\]

c
\[
\bigintss_0^x \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^2}dz
\]

\end{document}
```